# Gravity is relative and not absolute?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I was messing around with fluid simulations, and I noticed that if I rotate the domain, the direction of gravity rotates with the z axis of the domain. Can I make it so that gravity is always pointing in -z, and not -z relative to the domain?

I know I can calculate gravity for each direction and set that in the options of the domain, but I'm too lazy for that :/

file: https://easyupload.io/51rm22

Comment: i am pretty sure that you shouldn't rotate the domain and that it doesn't make what you hope it should make. The domain shouldn't be moved at all. If you want such an effect, make an effector in your domain, fill in a fluid in that effector and rotate that effector. The domain is just a theoretical construct, it is not a "real time" object like an effector. It is just the bounds of your simulation. Not more and not less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ... transforming domain's rotation calculates sim gravity in Local Z axis. Hard to say if it is for result stability (avoid some issues or glitches) or missing feature. Anyway you can set gravity global for domain like this ...

- For **Domain** > *Field Weigths > Gravity* set zero
- Add **Empty** > *Force Field > Shape-Plane > Force* and set *Strenght* -9.81

[image]

Note:
In another post here I had to specify *Domain > Field Weights* > set *Collection* at some point to make it work, but when later deleted it worked as well. So probably some file specific issue.

Comment: Nice solution !!!