# Water not flowing out of effector

Tags: physics, mantaflow

I was making an orange smoothie sim but then I realized that when I wanted the water to pour down the glass cup the liquid sticks, I haven't enabled viscosity and I keyframed the initial velocity on the z axis and tried re-baking, also, The domain is bigger so it can flow down. Can anyone help?

[image: water not flowing out of effector]

[image]

Comment: Share your file https://blend-exchange.com/ ... Probably your domain is too big with low divisions resolution, so liquid is not generated.

Comment: but i set the resolutions divisions to 70

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=yRggM7MO" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/yRggM7MO/)

Comment: could you please describe exactly what you want to do? I find it weird that for example the domain rotates, it will make the simulation rotate as well, etc

Comment: It doesn't move because you are transforming domain. Sim still calculates gravity to Domain's Local Z axis. [Try this if solves your issue.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/257948/2214) BTW Given code you should placed into your Q (not as a comment), thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work with that link

Comment: It works for me ... https://imgur.com/KrFyGen ... try Domain > Field Weights > set Collection ... for some reason I had to set some, later it worked also without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first rule for using any simulation - rigid body, soft body cloth, mantaflow...apply your scale on all objects which are part of the simulation.

second rule for mantaflow: the domain is not to be made to move. As long as you are a beginner and as you obviously don't know what you are doing, just don't move it. Everything inside the domain and outside can move - just don't move the domain.

third rule for mantaflow: watch closely the little resolution cube in one corner of your domain. This is your absolutely minimum resolution of your flow. Everything which is important for the simulation should be bigger than that e.g. effector walls so that water cannot make it through.

After stopping your domain to move and resizing it, applying all scales, adding a solidify modifier to your cup (which doesn't make it looking good but it works), i got this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Of course i didn't take a too high resolution - because i was lazy and didn't want to waste my time.

You have to take a much higher resolution and tweak the size of the cup in that way that it "holds" the water or...use just an invisible cup as effector parented to your cup which is often the better solution.